# Flutter In app purchases history is empty

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase

Hello I have implemented the following [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) and I have uploaded an apk as Alpha release and I bought the item I have created at App Store.

But when I buy a product with the test card after a while the order is canceled and removed from the history without me consuming it, is this something that is happening only one the test cards ??? Also If I move my apk to BETA would I be able to use real physical card to make a payment ?

Those are the things I couldn't figure out on my own can anyone throw some light, please ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a in app purchase validation problem